# Left Side Navigation partially showing when it is set to inherit from parent - I've checked out the answers below

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the top site of my collection set to navigation - managed - using the term store I have GF Navigation - I have added some new navigation terms - they are partially showing up in the left navigation for sites below the top site - I have checked the quick launch is on, and inherit from parent - not sure where else to look